# Convert SILK encoded data to wav file in python

Tags: python-3.x, audio, codec, silk

I was surprised I couldn't find an answer to this from a search - maybe I'm using the wrong search terms.

I have what I suspect is a silk compressed datastream (see below) that I would like to turn into a audio file (something like wav ideally). I'm planning on doing this in python, however I have no idea how to do this - I don't get any reasonable searches for how to decompresses the data with silk - maybe there's no silk packages for python (?).

Silk data:
*uz+ACgEAEAELgD4EQgEWAKV4mxnepfmhxKCQxAnKVNaHhKRXPIsmAH5RjXmJV0u+WTmrvgyCKxcraehjo/ZeKcFjksXQZEeOju4hLNv/MAB9KA7ww14Vc0ndYPB7dDXoXTexuxcW0Jg/diMgdH5ijWhe02Ch48KX86qJZYFyZV81AH76qCgh9AXliMdyWEgWTMbRD6xMX37WJALrXlSnxymIloSq2KGwXCcMXzQiSQIrcLVNfqdNJACCluFOIRKPmugUvsLZmnD04X0xhpAuNkwJECK4t51MBOWNWJlCAIDyZlJwWI45EPTjBB6yKyGOclu96qBV2MhFAh1d2J7WDZwe6YxOVu/BGkGcur9qTP85ZRfjANoiQxQrWvpoHFBFBy0AfX6k8XvbSwrk2nUAEP3P6kcmXORKUNKeu8HDnOUflQqtA5AkkTiun77fZrqnimIfWg==*

Answer (score 1):

First, validate your assumption that it is SILK.
If you open an encoded binary file, it should start with the header "#!SILK_V3". Your excerpt seems like some base64 encoding  (maybe the raw binary?).
If you do get to the real silk data, you can decode it with the original [Skype Silk SDK](https://github.com/kn007/silk-v3-decoder/tree/master/silk/src). There is probably no python port for this, but you can invoke external libs from python.
Once decoded, use ffmpeg/Audacity raw import/other to convert to WAV/mp3 and test the audio. Then in python, using the wave library or wavio api should work.